# Mysql wont load user data of application

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I just copied an application from my local `dev` env to `prod` env, and my data is not loading for my flask app instead its showing `no blog posts right now...`

I've verified the following:

- db user has permission to table.
- mysql is running
- verified query again (works fine)
- tried messing with `MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST` set to `localhost` and `xx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to no avail.
- verified my import (`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` is working fine for `mysql`) - it is

**app.py**:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecret'

# mail server config
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'mailserver.net'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'contact@mysite.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypass'


# mysql config
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3306'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']   = 'mydb'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'myusr'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypass'

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
c = mysql.connect().cursor()
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
    form = EmailForm()

c.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name, YEAR(post_date) as YEAR, MONTH(post_date) as MONTH FROM mydb.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")
    blogposts = c.fetchall()

    print(blogposts)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return 'Please fill in all fields <p><a href="/">Try Again</a></p>'
        else:
            msg = Message("Message from your visitor",
                          sender='contact@mysite.com',
                          recipients=['contact@mysite.com'])
            msg.body = """
            From: %s
            """ % (form.email.data)
            mail.send(msg)
            return render_template('email_submit_thankyou.html')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, blogposts=blogposts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`templates/index.html` contains:

```
<ul>
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
    <li><a href="mysite.com/wordpress/{{blogpost[2]}}/{{blogpost[3]}}/{{blogpost[1]}}">{{blogpost[0]}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li>no blog posts right now...</li>
    {% endfor %}
<div class="clearL"> </div>
</ul>
```

I found a "slow" query in `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log`:

```
# Time: 170101 16:34:32
# User@Host: myuser[myuser] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 0.004649  Lock_time: 0.001712 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 53
SET timestamp=1483306472;
SELECT
        post_title, post_name, YEAR(post_date) as YEAR, MONTH(post_date) as MONTH
FROM mydb.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

Thus, What is going wrong here?

Comment: its an else statement, if no results are found

Comment: Are you sure that your db has data? You have copied code but what about database?

Comment: In fact, seeing closer, your SQL has a syntax issue. Column aliases must be qualified with `AS` operator

Comment: @Parfait - the query is **not** the issue. I've tested it.

Comment: Really? In SQL, every column alias needs `AS`. The posted query here should not work. Also, you may be leaving a bit of code out. You have indentation that would fail in Python. Are we missing a method? Also, you don't initialize app with `app = Flask(__name__)` or run `@app.route('/')`. Does *form* in email method render in template? Any jinja errors? Code in SO posts should compile and reproduce issue.

Comment: @Parfait - the `query` was tested on both the production env and local dev environment database via `mysql workbench`. Adding to `app.py` above so that maybe you can help me.

Comment: @Parfait - please see `app.py` updated above with more code as requested.

Comment: @Parfait - also see the log data I found in `mysql-slow.log` under: `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log` the `query` is returning 3 rows from the db.

Comment: So with this fuller script (changed considerably), in both prod and dev env, you only get *no blog posts right now...* in html's `<ul>` tags? And again I ask does *form* render in template?

Comment: @Parfait - Yes, `form` is rendered. In `dev` the blog posts show up, in `prod` they arent showing up and the `no blog posts` is returned

Comment: Ah-ha! So your code is fine. The issue is your environment. Usually databases differ in envs. Possibly, *blogposts* in *mydb.wp_posts* in prod is empty? Your posted log is localhost version (usually dev env). In prod env, does *blogposts* print anything on `print(blogposts)` line?

Comment: Actually, i found the offending line - this line: `c = mysql.connect().cursor()` is killing `production` - thoughts?

Comment: Forget the above, even before that, its failing on `app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(app)` thoughts?

Comment: So it appears it has trouble making connection to the `mysql` db, and creating the `cursor` - is my syntax wrong?